# j2me mobile phone/pc chat application using SMS

Tags: java, java-me, mobile-phones, wireless

I am completelly naive to J2me, but I proposed to do a chat application using SMS for my wireless application assignment, is it possible. The computer aint a phone, it has no number, I suppose. How can I start, I only have 2 weeks to do it....Any ideas?

Comment: your question is not clear, do you want your pc to send sms to the phone?

Comment: Yes, I need the computer and mobile phone to communicate in real time via SMS technology wirelessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Wireless Messaging API (WMA) that might be worth looking at. I'll point you in the right direction. Maybe start looking [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/sending-receiving-sms-on-j2me-device-3.html) and [here](http://freecode-freecode.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-send-sms-in-j2me.html). These two examples should give you what you need. Let me know if that helps at all.